# how to make open sans font selectable in R when making a pdf

Tags: r, pdf

I want to make a pdf in R and have the text written in open sans (e.g. created with a call to text()) be selectable.

Usually, text made in a pdf is selectable e.g.

```
pdf(file="NiceLFile.pdf",width=8,height=8, pointsize=10)
plot(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,1),type="n")
text(x=0.5, y=0.5, adj=c(0.5,0.5), labels="lower case l text")
dev.off()
```

But this isn't the case when I use open sans

```
library(showtext)
dest2 <- file.path(tempdir(), "open-sans.light.ttf")
download.file("http://ff.static.1001fonts.net/o/p/open-sans.light.ttf", dest2, mode = "wb")
font.add("light", regular = dest2)
showtext.auto()
pdf(file="ChunkyLFile.pdf",width=8,height=8, pointsize=10)
plot(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,1),type="n")
text(x=0.5, y=0.5, adj=c(0.5,0.5), family="light", labels="lower case l text")
dev.off()
```

what can I do to make the text selectable?

Comment: That behavior is dependent on operating system and screen resolution, but has nothing to do with R. The underlying PDF is the same regardless of how it's displayed.

Comment: Knowing how to make R export pdfs with the text as text is a legitimate question. The opinion of the folks at Adobe is that text should be in a pdf as text--and there is some logic to that.

Comment: R already makes text selectable by default. Your question seems to be about how PDFs are displayed.

Comment: Can you select the text in the pdf made by the above code? I can't.

Comment: Your comment was actually helpful. It appears that it's my use of open sans that is the issue. Adobe Reader does not cause these problems for text. So, the question really appears to be about how to get open sans to be selectable in a pdf file.

Comment: I'm not particularly inclined to install a package for the question, but since I've already got Open Sans installed, this works: `cairo_pdf() ; plot(1, xlab = 'foo foo was a bunny', family = 'Open Sans Light') ; dev.off()`, as does `ggplot(data.frame(x = 'foo foo was a bunny')) + geom_text(aes(0, 0, label = x)) + theme_void() ; ggsave('Rplot.pdf')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125039/discussion-between-paul-bailey-and-alistaire).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do this on windows:

1. Open Sans must be installed on the machine, see 
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170113/is-it-possible-to-download-open-sans-as-available-on-google-fonts-to-use-on-my-d).
2. extrafont can then install it into R see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/README.html)
3. Then, as alistaire notes, you can call pdf with the fonts argument set equal to the fonts that you want to render as text rather than normal vector graphics.

then you can do

```
require(extrafont)
pdf(file="SelectableFile.pdf",width=8,height=8, pointsize=10, fonts=c("Open Sans Light"))
plot(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,1),type="n")
text(x=0.5, y=0.5, adj=c(0.5,0.5), family="Open Sans Light", labels="lower case l text")
dev.off()
```

You may also need to embed the font in the pdf

```
embed_fonts(file="SelectableFile.pdf",outfile ="SelectableFile.pdf")
```